# how to filter a componet by id in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am learn reactjs and hand one project,but I could not completely fiddle some branch of the whole.I post the code below:
in the App.js:import React, { useState } from "react";

```
import colorData from "./color-data.json";
import ColorList from "./ColorList.js";

export default function App() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(colorData);

  const removeColor = id => {
    const newColors = colors.filter(color => color.id !== id);
    setColors(newColors);
  };

  const rateColor = (id, rating) => {
    const newColors = colors.map(color =>
      color.id === id ? { ...color, rating } : color
    );
    setColors(newColors);
  };

  return (
    <ColorList
      colors={colors}
      onRemoveColor={removeColor}
      onRateColor={rateColor}
    />
  );
}
```

what is the "color => color.id !== id" used for?are they not the same: "color.id" and "id"
it is the project link:https://codesandbox.io/s/learning-react-color-organizer-2-forked-ke1gz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`color => color.id !== id` is a predicate that's used to remove the color of the id that is passed to your `removeColor` function.

How this works is the filter function will iterate through each item of the array (colors in this example) and pass that item to a function you provide to check if it should be removed from the list. If the function is true, it's removed.

`color => color.id !== id` is the function that's called for each item, so if the current color's id equals the id that is passed to the `removeColor` function, then it's removed.

One thing to note is the original array isn't changed, it just returns a new array (`newColors`) with the items removed.

```
// function that takes an id as a parameter
const removeColor = id => {
  // remove the color of the id that is passed by using the filter function
  const newColors = colors.filter(color => color.id !== id);
  // update your state with filtered colors
  setColors(newColors);
};
```

Comment: The id is passed from `Color.js`. Look at `<button onClick={() => onRemove(id)}>`. That calls `removeColor` on in `App.js` with the color you are clicking.

Comment: If you don't understand this sample, you should start with something more simple.

Comment: hi,thanks,but I am stupid so I can not agree with you.In App.js, the  `id` which is passed to the `removeColor` is from `<ColorList onRemoveColor={removeColor}` which is from ` <Color onRemove={onRemoveColor}` of `ColorList.js`which is from `onRemove(id)` in `Color.js`,so it is just a 'string' and not defined,the`color.id`in `App.js` is the `key`value,so absolutely `color.id` would not be equal to `id` forever,the `filter` could not work to delete any value and return a new array `newColors`.Please pump my head with your answer,thanks gentleman.

Comment: `color-data.json` has your `color.id`. That's imported into `App.js` as `colorData` and initializes `colors`. `colors` is mapped on `ColorList.js` and using `{...color}` you are passing `id` as a prop to each component `Color.js`. `id` is then passed to the remove button when you click the button, the filter matches the id.

Answer (score 0):

The function removeColor takes in the parameter of `id` which is the id of the color to remove Using the [Array.filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

The way filters works is it iterates through the array and whatever property fulfills the boolean condition in this case `color.id !== id` where `color` is an arbitrary element within the array and `id` is what is passed in as a parameter to the `removeColor` function.

More info on how `Array.filter` works here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: hi,thanks,but I am stupid so I can not agree with you.In App.js, the  `id` which is passed to the `removeColor` is from `<ColorList onRemoveColor={removeColor}` which is from ` <Color onRemove={onRemoveColor}` of `ColorList.js`which is from `onRemove(id)` in `Color.js`,so it is just a 'string' and not defined,the`color.id`in `App.js` is the `key`value,so absolutely `color.id` would not be equal to `id` forever,the `filter` could not work to delete any value and return a new array `newColors`.Please pump my head with your answer,thanks gentleman.